# dhpcd hogging all recources

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cpu, minecraft

I manage a Linux server for my friend which runs a Minecraft server, I consider myself a total noob in Linux but i know how to work with it a little.

Since the server is at my friend's house I use powershell to ssh into the server and start the startup script inside a `screen`. But after a while a process starts running `/bin/dhcpcd` and it always uses at least 50% of the CPU power. It also starts when I don't start the minecraft server but it never runs at startup.

What is this, can I disable it and if so how?

Comment: Try uninstalling the respective package.

Answer (score 1):

do you mean "dhpcd" or "dhcpcd", because I had the same issue,
"dhpcd" is a trojan (or at least a not a good program), I recommend you copy you server files and do a reinstall.

(I know the question is a year old, just want to clear up if someone stumbles on this thread)